# Use value from checkbox in query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a checkbox input with value set to 0.

```
<form id="formFilter2" name="formFilter2" method="post" action="">
    <input name="selView" type="checkbox" id="selView" onChange="formFilter2.submit()" 
     value="0" <?php echo (isset($_POST['selView'])?'checked':'');?> />
     view accounts with no fees assigned
</form>
```

I set up a query that is Left Join to a table that (fees) counts how many fees an account has. When I view the data I can see the count after every corresponding members.Name. 0 shows up if there is no record in the fees table with the members.ID. Some members have not been assigned a fee. I am trying to use the checkbox to filter the names and show me which have 0 assigned.

```
$varView_RecordsetMembers = "%";
if (isset($_POST['selView'])) {
  $varView_RecordsetMembers = $_POST['selView'];
}

$varFilter_RecordsetMembers = "%";
if (isset($_POST['selFilter'])) {
$varFilter_RecordsetMembers = $_POST['selFilter'];
}

$colname_RecordsetMembers = "%";
if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
$colname_RecordsetMembers = $_GET['search'];
}

$query_RecordsetMembers = sprintf("SELECT DISTINCT members.Tag, members.ID, members.Name, 
COALESCE((COUNT(CASE WHEN fees.Type='Fee' THEN fees.ID END)) ,0) AS 'Feez' FROM members 
LEFT JOIN fees ON members.ID=fees.ID WHERE (members.Dept LIKE %s AND (members.Name LIKE %s 
OR members.ID LIKE %s)) GROUP BY members.ID HAVING 'Feez' LIKE %s ORDER BY members.Name, 
members.Dept", GetSQLValueString($varFilter_RecordsetMembers, "text"),
GetSQLValueString("%" . $colname_RecordsetMembers . "%", "text"),
GetSQLValueString("%" . $colname_RecordsetMembers . "%", "text"), 
GetSQLValueString($varView_RecordsetMembers, "text"));
```

By default the records show all members and I would like to use the checkbox to toggle between all members and filter to those with no fees. When I view the data I can see the count after every corresponding members.Name. 0 shows up if there is no record in the fees table with the members.ID. Some members have not been assigned a fee. I am trying to use the checkbox to filter the names and show me which have 0 assigned. I am using HAVING 'Feez' LIKE %s (or COUNT) to query the data to show on ly the members with no records or fees. I even tried to use COALESCE with no success. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's that `GetSQLValueString()` function, and can you call it like that: separately to the same SQL string?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are proposing. I have used the same code for use with option menues or seach boxes.